# Best practices for reading remote files with php

Tags: php, readfile

In php when you open a socket connection. you can do it like this:

```
$fp = @stream_socket_client ( $hosts, $errno, $errstr, 120, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT );
```

or this :

```
$fp = @fsockopen($Host , $Port, $errno, $errstr, 15);
```

then you want to get a file

We can do this with a various functions `fgets` `fread` `stream_get _line` etc

**What is the best practice for get the better results and higher speed of transfer?**

Comment: Why not try all versions and post a nice benchmark?

Comment: Sure I will do that, Where I can post it?

Comment: post it here as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely subjective to your platform and configuration. Sockets will provide a very efficient transfer, but you'll have to do all the HTTP/FTP request stuff yourself if you want to get a file.

Your best bet is just to try them out yourself and see how it performs.

Comment: I am doing as you said, I wanted to know if there is any specific hint :)

Comment: Well, you shouldn't really use `fgets` or `stream_get_line` for this anyway. They'll read until they hit a newline, which isn't (usually) desirable on network streamed files. As such, I would guess that fread or sockets will perform best.